# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I am trying to make a Twitter bot that will automatically reply, like, and Retweet the Tweet which mentions a certain `#`. In the code below, whenever someone mentions the bot and `#amrevx` in their Tweet, it's going to automatically reply, like, Retweet, and also store the Tweet ID so it does not go on replying to the same Tweet in a loop. But when it finds a Tweet and serves its purpose, it stops running and sends the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    reply()
  File "main.py", line 44, in reply
    store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)
  File "main.py", line 27, in store_last_seen
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

```
import tweepy
import os
import time


consumer_key = (os.getenv("c.key"))
consumer_secret = (os.getenv("c.secret"))

key = (os.getenv("key"))
secret = (os.getenv("secret"))

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'

def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen = str(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen

def store_last_seen(last_seen, FILE_NAME):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen))
    file_write.close()
    return

def reply():
    print('retrieving and replying to tweets...', flush=True)
    last_seen = read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)
    tweets = api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode = 'extended')
    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
        if '#amrevx' in tweet.full_text.lower():
            print(str(tweet.id) + '-' + tweet.full_text) 
            last_seen = tweet.id
            store_last_seen(last_seen, FILE_NAME)
            api.update_status("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " Auto reply, like, and retweet work :)" , tweet.id)
            api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)

while True:
    reply()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: "FILE_NAME" seems to be an int. The shown code is not enough to tell you why. But it looks as if you mixed argument order for "store_last_seen".

Comment: Please post the remaining code, especially `store_last_seen` function

Comment: This is the whole code

Answer (score 0):

On the last line of your reply function, you have `store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)`.
You're passing `FILE_NAME` as `last_seen` and `tweet.id` as `FILE_NAME`, instead of the other way around.